# Gallery using Photobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using the following code for a gallery in AngularJS but if I try to use it without AngularJS it doesn't seems to work. If I run it with AngularJS then it will open the images properly but if I run it normally it will open the image as  Can anyone to explain to me the difference?

app.js (AngularJS)

```
app.controller('GalleryController', function() { 

  var gallery = $('#gallery'),
  gallery1 = $('#gallery1');

  console.log("init gallery");

  $('#gallery').photobox('a', {
      thumbs: true,
      loop: false
  }, callback);

  $('#gallery1').photobox('a', {
      thumbs: true,
      loop: false
  }, callback);

  function callback(){
      console.log('image has been loaded');
  }

   console.log("GALLERY CONTROLLER BEGIN");

});
```

gallery.html (jQuery)

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var gallery = $('#gallery'),
    gallery1 = $('#gallery1');

  console.log("init gallery");

  $('#gallery').photobox('a', {
      thumbs: true,
      loop: false
  }, callback);

  $('#gallery1').photobox('a', {
      thumbs: true,
      loop: false
  }, callback);

  function callback(){
      console.log('image has been loaded');
  }

   console.log("GALLERY CONTROLLER BEGIN");

});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console? that would help a lot...

Comment: Thats's the weird thing. There is no error

Comment: The anonymous function in second example is not invoking itself, therefor it's never called. To invoke it, add a parenthesis after the closure: `});` -> `})();`

Comment: Now I receive 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined' in console for 'var gallery = $('#gallery')'

Comment: In this case, you need to add jQuery to your project. `$` is the convenient shorthand for `jQuery`. **Edit**: If the script is called before the DOM is loaded, you may need to remove the parantheses as mentioned before and just add a $ in front of the parentheses in the first line: `$(function () { });` See: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Done. Was the order of my library that my script was running before jQuery